# Add tick mark to selected item in ListAdapter

Tags: java, android

I have list of name in ListAdapter, I show icon and icon's name.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;

    if (convertView == null) {
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_icon_text, parent, false);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }

    AppModel item = getItem(position);

        ImageView myicon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iconList);
        myicon.setImageDrawable(item.getIcon()); 
              ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textList)).setText(item.getLabel());

    }

    return view;
}
```

Now, I want to click the name and view a tick mark at the right side to indicate that it have been selected, tick mark should be invisible when it selected again. So far I have failed trying put the tick mark icon as ImageView because sometimes when I click A, H also has tick mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the `convertView`, the issue like you said is normal.To solve the problem,you can do like this:

1. add `boolean selected` attribute to `AppModel`

   ```
   public class AppModel {


   //....
   //your own attributes


   private boolean selected;

   public boolean isSelected() {
       return selected;
   }

   public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
       this.selected = selected;
   }
   ```

   }
2. add `tick ImageView` to your layout. when inflate item view use `boolean 
   selected` to control whether to show the tick.

   ```
    AppModel item = getItem(position);
    ImageView tick = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.tick);
    tick.setVisibility(item.isSelected()?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
   ```
3. add `OnClickListener` to your view:

   ```
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           item.setSelected(!item.isSelected());
           notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
   });
   ```